# How to insert content from html code template from different database table

Tags: php

I am trying to create a html code template. The problem is there are two html code template saved on different table my problem is merging the two codes when generating.

Here is a simple example:

Database Table 1 - this is where I store the structure of the html section:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
          // content will be put here
    </div>
</div>
```

Database Table 2 - this is where I store the content that will be going inside on what's inside the Table 1.

```
<h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
<p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
```

When generated the html code should look like this

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason I did like this is because the contents inside are flexible meaning can be added, removed, reorganized. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: do you have any knowledge on ajax? [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) can exactly serve the purpose for you.

Comment: @RajuAhmed yes I have but I am trying to limit on using php only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an anchor on your first table.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
          <my-unique-tag>
    </div>
</div>
```

and replace that anchor with your second table data.

```
$result = str_replace('<my-unique-tag>', $secondData, $firstData);
```